# Visual Studio 2010 call stack window stripping template parameter types

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates

I am currently writing and debugging a library that makes heavy use of templates as policy classes. Therefore, instantiated objects types are templates of template of...

Looking at the visual studio (2010) call stack window (as well as the output windows) makes it impossible to get the name of the function at a glance, because it lies at the end of three lines of signature.

The call stack window has several options to show/hide the parameter types/values, and other things, but none of these make the template types disappear. Ideally, I would like to be able to see the class name, stripped of all template parameters, and the function name (and revert to the current visualization to resolve ambiguities). Does this option exist?

Comment: what version of Visual Studio?

Comment: edit: I am using VS2010, but this applies to older versions as well

Comment: Perhaps this is helpfull: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx